# QGIS attribute input format

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

is there a way to enter a numger in the field and the data would fill up according to my specifications?? example : i have to name things that has fixed names only different numbers that are related ..such as the format is "FATx-FDTxx-OLTxxx" and id write only 36 and the data would show "FAT36-FDT9-OLT"

more explaning:

im trying to have a fixed format input in qgis with simple changes .. for example in one of the layers has an attribute field that is practically the same "FAT1-FDT1-OLT1" "FAT6-FDT2-OLT1" and so on

so what im trying to accomplish is having a default input of the "FAT - FDT -OLT" and then i enter the numbers .. i used the text default in the fields properties 
but those numbers are related as in the FAT numbers go through 64,the FDT number cycle from 1-4... so now im trying to figure out an easy way to write in the input only the number and the rest would just show up .. example : id write only 36 and the data would show "FAT36-FDT9-OLT"

is there a way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format or concatenate text using Field calculator:

**Syntax to update an existing field using "Source" field:**

```
'FATx-FDT' + concat( "Source" ) + '-FDT9-OLT'
```

[image: Example]

**Source:**
https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html

Comment: this is great 
just one more thing.. can i add a math function to it, as in itd be FAT("source")-FDT(source-1)%4+1-olt(source  /  20)

Comment: Of course, check the link n u can find all types of formatting and also you can use python to create functions